# Large sorted datatable "wraps" around

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, datatable, duplicates

I am attempting to remove duplicates from a .NET datatable consisting of more than 50,000 rows. My approach is simple: I want to sort the datatable alphabetically, then scan through looking for rows that are the same as the row above it.

The problem I'm having is that the datatable "wraps" around when sorted. I use this to sort it:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "name";
```

When I view the datatable using the debugger, it is sorted alphabetically in chunks, like so:

```
Aardvark
Apple
Banana
...(20,000 rows later)...
Aardvark
Angle
Boat
```

Obviously this ruins my attempt to find duplicates. Is this some sort of optimization behavior of the framework when dealing with large tables? What is going on here?

Solution:

Here is what I was doing..

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "name";
for (int i =0; i< myDataTable.DefaultView.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var thisRow = myDataTable.DefaultView.Table.Rows[i];
    var prevRow = myDataTable.DefaultView.Table.Rows[i-1];
}
```

Here is what I should have been doing:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort="name";
var myNewDatatable = myDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
for (int i =0; i< myNewDatatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var thisRow = myNewDatatable.Rows[i];
    var prevRow = myNewDatatable.Rows[i-1];
}
```

Comment: What is the data source? If it's a database can't you just do this using SQL statements?

Comment: A DataGridView loaded from CSV. I've found that I can remove duplicates by cloning the table (there is a 'distinct' parameter on that method) but it is really slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "name";
```

Here you're sorting the `DataView` for the `DataTable` and not the `DataTable`.
So you have to either use the `DataView` (`myDataTable.DefaultView`)
or getting the `DataRow`'s of the `DataTable` sorted by name

```
DataRow[] sorted = myDataTable.Select("", "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b6ehaa.aspx) overload to accomplish this.

```
DataTable uniqueTable = myDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable("UniqueStuff", true, "SomeCol", "AnotherCol", "YetAnotherCol");
```